# I need a check on,if the user enter a same username or password in db,code needs to tell them.it already exists.but its not working here

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, database-connection

```
<?php
$errors=array();
session_start();
if(!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])){
$errors[]="enter name";
}

elseif(!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])){
$errors[]="enter mail id";
}
elseif(!isset($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
$errors[]="enter password";
}

else{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("failed establishing connection");
$db=mysql_select_db("sam",$con) or die("failed establishing db connection"); 


$query="SELECT * FROM user_account";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result) or die('errors');


if($row[1]==$name){
echo"username already exists";

}
elseif($row[3]==$email){
echo "Email already exists";

}


else
{



$sql=" INSERT  INTO user_account ('username','password','email') VALUES('$name','$password','$email') " or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($result)
{
echo "insertion done";

}
else
{
echo "insertion failed";
}
}
}






if(count($errors)>0){
foreach($errors as $err){
echo $err;
}
}  



?>
```

i need to make a check if the username and entered by the user already exists in the database or not.For that i have added if loop to check it.,but each time user enter a same username it shows error message but after correcting the error by the user the error message still persist.its not moving to next elseif loop..hw can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You Query is wrong, you just select all useres that exist. You should select where username and password and email equal the input and check for num rows 1 or 0.